# onActivityResult Uri - create subfolder and get DocumentUri of new subfolder

Tags: android, uri, create-directory, documentfile

I take the result of my file chooer in `onActivityResult` an build a `DocumentUriUsingTree`.
Now I take this `DocumentUri`, build a `DocumentFile` to create a new folder.

onActivityResult:

```
if (resultCode  == RESULT_OK) {
                    
                    uri = data.getData();

                    int takeFlags = data.getFlags();
                    takeFlags &= (Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION |
                            Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION );

                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT <= Build.VERSION_CODES.O_MR1) {
                        getContext().getContentResolver().takePersistableUriPermission(uri,
                                Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION |
                                        Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION
                        );
                    }

                    DocumentFile subfolderDf = DocumentFile.fromTreeUri(this,uri);
                    subfolderDf.createDirectory("TestFolder");

                    uriDirFolder = uri.toString();
                    editor = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
                    editor.putString(PREF_FILE_OBSERVER, uriDirFolder);
                    editor.apply();
}
```

resultUri == uriDirFolder get from `SharedPreference` get-Methode

```
Uri docUriTree = DocumentsContract.buildDocumentUriUsingTree(Uri.parse(resultUri), DocumentsContract.getTreeDocumentId(Uri.parse(resultUri)));
```

`docTreeUri =  content://com.android.externalstorage.documents/tree/3339-6133%3AStorage%20Card%2FMusic%....`

```
DocumentFile df = DocumentFile.fromTreeUri(this, docUriTree);
DocumentFile dirDf = df.createDirectory(dirName);
```

dirDf looks like `content://com.android.externalstorage.documents/tree/3339-6133%3AStorage%....dirName`

```
df = DocumentFile.fromTreeUri(this,dirDf.getUri());
```

df returns the parent folder and not the new created folder

I need the `DocumentFileUri` from the new folder to use an `OutputStream`on it for saving files into it.

What I'm doing wrong here?

Thanks,
Alejandro

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> DocumentFile subfolderDf = DocumentFile.fromTreeUri(this,uri);
> subfolderDf.createDirectory("TestFolder");

Change to:

```
            DocumentFile folder = DocumentFile.fromTreeUri(this, uri);
            DocumentFile subfolder = folder.createDirectory("TestFolder");

            if ( subfolder == null )
            {
                Toast.makeText(context, "Sorry, could not create a subfolder with name TestFolder", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                return;
            }

            Toast.makeText(context, "Created a subfolder with name TestFolder: " + subfolder.getUri().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Comment: thank you. this small but essential change has solved the problem for me.